# join query not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select two table values so I am using join query see below, from this code I stored one session variable like `$_SESSION['emp_id']`, I want select query like who are in `te.emp_id='".$_SESSION['emp_id']."'`, From this code `$count` will return 0 but in my database I have one row.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT *
                    FROM task_employee te
                    JOIN task t
                      ON te.emp_id = t.t_assign_to
                    WHERE t.t_status = '0'
                      AND t.t_delete_on != '1'
                      AND te.emp_id = '" . $_SESSION['emp_id'] . "'");
$data = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $data[] = $r;
}  
$count = sizeof($data);
if($count > 0)
{ 
    $return = array('status'=>'success', 'count'=>sizeof($data), 'data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
else
{
    $return=array('status'=>'not-found', 'count'=>sizeof($data), 'data'=>$data);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

I am writing like this means I can get but using join query that time I can't get values

```
<?php
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
                          FROM task
                          WHERE t_delete_on !='1'
                            AND t_assign_to = '$emp_id'");
    for ($i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); $i++)
    {
        $assign_to = $row['t_assign_to']; 
        $mysql = mysql_query("SELECT *
                                FROM task_employee
                                WHERE emp_id = '$assign_to'");
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql))
        {
            $emp_name = $r['emp_firstname']; // here i got value 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You might want to check for the datatypes and make sure that they are of the same type.

Comment: same datatype only

Comment: will you show your database example

Comment: Oh sorry,this code working supper...

Comment: You say it's working now?